# Changing case at the end of a word in Vim

Tags: vim

I know **gUw** will turn **properties** to **PROPERTIES** and stay at the first character of the word.

But if I use **gUb**, it will be **PROPERTIEs** and cursor at the first charactoer.

If I use **gUge**, it will be **PROPERTIES** but cursor at last word.

What should I do if I want to turn the word to upper case, and stay at the end of the word(so that i can keep on typing without a **w**)

Answer (score 2):

All operator+motion edits will leave the cursor on the first character of the motion. From `:help motion.txt`:

> After applying the operator the cursor is mostly left at the start of the text that was operated upon.  For example, "yfe" doesn't move the cursor, but "yFe" moves the cursor leftwards to the "e" where the yank started.

So, assuming your cursor is on the last character of the current word:

```
properties
         ^
```

there is no built-in way to ensure that the cursor will stay there after an operator+motion edit.

One can leave a mark and jump back to it after the edit:

```
m'gUiw``
```

but that's more work than just pressing `w`. It could be turned into a mapping, though, if that's a common need:

```
nnoremap <key> m'gUiw``
```

but that doesn't sound very scalable.

Another approach would be to record your edit:

```
qq
m'gUiw``
q
```

and play it back as needed:

```
@q
```

But your last sentence is puzzling:

> What should I do if I want to turn the word to upper case, and stay at the end of the word(so that i can keep on typing without a **w**)

If you are at the end of:

```
 properties
          ^
```

and your edit leaves the cursor at the beginning of:

```
 PROPERTIES
 ^
```

`w` will move the cursor to the beginning of the next word:

```
 PROPERTIES foo
            ^
```

and not to the end of the current word.

We are missing some context, here.

Comment: That's enlightening. I just thought there is a way to stay at the end so a **w** is not neccessary. It doesn't matter now.